# Listening to Kafka & pulling data into Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, kafka

I am going say right off the bat that I am not fluent in SF event architecture.
My question is can SF listen to Kafka event bus in real time and when Kafka listener alerts a change, SF should be able to call and get that data from Kafka and create record in SF.

And just for some clarity, using another tool in the middle to connect SF-Kafka isn't in budget. So the requirement is to integrate SF and Kafka directly.

Is that even possible?
I looked at streaming api but that works when record changes are taking place in SF and not in external system.
I even read some posts on StackExchange about it. But I couldn't get a clear cut answer.
Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Via a native event streaming protocol such as CometD - the answer is no. The approach is to call SF APIs from Kafka. You can string that together with an OSS or paid connector in Kafka. Examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest or https://github.com/nodefluent/salesforce-kafka-connect